# JDK classes seem to be not on Studio classpath. please ensure you run the ide on jdk rather than jre ubuntu

Tags: android-studio

After downloading android studio in ubuntu, when I run the ./studio.sh file in bin dir, it shows the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: the error still here even u just dwnload the jdk.